# How to change password complexity for mailbox in exchange 2013

Tags: windows, security, exchange, password, exchange-2013

I find the default password policy in exchange pretty weak (only 6 char.). Is there a way to change this password policy ?

e.g. : Minimum 1 cap, Minimum 8 letters.

Thank you !

Comment: Exchange doesn't have a password policy, iirc. You need to be looking towards the account settings in the windows domains your exchange org is hosting accounts for.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more please ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an Exchange policy per se, but a Windows Active Directory Domain group policy. You can specify password length. You can also specify "require complex passwords" which the group policy defines as containing three of these four categories of characters:

- Lower case alphabet (a-z and diacriticals)
- Upper case alphabet (A-Z and diacriticals)
- Numerals (0-9)
- Symbols (~!@#$, etc.)

If you wish to define complexity differently, (i.e., minimum of one upper case) you will need to implement a custom password filter. The following articles discuss creating custom password filters:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721882(VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721766(VS.85).aspx